# Scan a document straight to my site

Tags: asp.net, scanning

I want to place a button in my ASP.NET Web Forms projec, that connects directly to my Scanner (hardware). Scan & Upload.

Is there a way to do so? 
(Activex, etc.)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try TwainX, it says.

"Easily integrate Scanners into your web-based applications with a minimum of ... of indirection"

http://twainx.sourceforge.net/

If this is an internal scanner accesible to your company, there is sense in doing this, but if  the general public has to do it, they will have to install the activex and all, not recommending your approach. Might as well ask the user to scan it, and then upload the image.

Answer (score 2):

This article - [Scan and Upload Documents in ASP.NET MVC App using Dynamic Web TWAIN](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618514/Scan-and-Upload-Documents-in-ASP-NET-MVC-App-using) - may help you as an alternative

Answer (score 1):

I found this post that includes source code that uses the ASP.NET to show how to scan on the client side and then upload the images onto the server:

http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/20960/ShowPost.aspx